# How to query and match two fields within one table in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I'm writing a JavaScript query within ServiceNow that will check a source file to a table within ServiceNow to verify

1. If the name of the county exists in the u_fips_county table and then
2. If it does exist in the table, I need it to match the county for that particular state (some counties have duplicate names in several states).

If the state name is the same and a county is in the table that matches that county name, under that state, then I want it to return that county name as being valid. If not, then I want it to show the errors listed and it will "ignore" the record and thus not input it into the target table.

Current Code:

```
(function runTransformScript(source, map, log, target /*undefined onStart*/) {

    var sourCountyName = source.u_county;
    var sourStateCode = source.u_state;
    var tabFipsCounty = new GlideRecord('u_fips_county');
    var tabFipsCounty2 = new GlideRecord('u_fips_county');
    tabFipsCounty.addQuery('u_county_full_state_name', sourStateCode);
    tabFipsCounty2.addQuery('u_county_name', sourCountyName);
    tabFipsCounty.query();
    tabFipsCounty2.query();

    if (tabFipsCounty.next()){

        if (sourStateCode == tabFipsCounty.u_county_full_state_name) {
            
            if (tabFipsCounty2.next()){

                if (sourCountyName == tabFipsCounty.u_county_name) {
                    var varifCounty = tabFipsCounty.u_county_name;
                    return varifCounty;
                }
            }
            else {
                log.error('There is no county named ' + sourCountyName + ' in the state of ' + sourStateCode + '.');
                ignore = true;
                }
        }
        else {
            log.error('The state two letter code, ' + sourStateCode + ', is misspelled or not a valid state.');
            ignore = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        log.error('There is no county, ' + sourCountyName + ', and/or state, ' + sourStateCode + ', in the FIPS County table.');
        ignore = true;
    }
    
//Below footer line used by ServiceNow for Transform Script
})(source, map, log, target);
```

I've run this and it seems to default out to the last "else" log.error line. Even if it finds the county, it doesn't match it to the state. So, say I'm trying to import "Lee" as a county name. There are several states that have a Lee county. It seems to just find the first Lee county and then matches it, even if the state should be Wisconsin, but it will take the first hit from Alabama.

I can't seem to get it to find the county name, then find the state with that county name, match the two and then return that County name record that has the correct state in it (instead of just finding either the first county that the name matches or a random county that the name matches, disregarding the state).

Comment: You test `tabFipsCounty2.next()` (with 2) but then you use `tabFipsCounty.u_county_name` (no 2) and never use the one with the 2. Looks wrong to me.

Comment: I appreciate the reply.  I'll have to look that back over.  I may have missed that, obviously.  LOL  Thank you.  I'll report back with an update.  :)

Comment: Ok, I edited the following code, but it still didn't exactly work properly.
``
if (tabFipsCounty2.next()){

                if (sourCountyName == tabFipsCounty2.u_county_name) {
                    var varifCounty = tabFipsCounty2.u_county_name;
                    return varifCounty;
``
It matched most, but as an example, Hampshire county in MA was skipped over because it was the second state listed with Hampshire county.  It is still not matching the state first.  It is just taking the first County name match.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
(function runTransformScript(source, map, log, target /*undefined onStart*/) {

    var sourCountyName = source.u_county;
    var sourStateCode = source.u_state;
    var tabFipsCounty = new GlideRecord('u_fips_county');
    tabFipsCounty.addQuery('u_county_full_state_name', sourStateCode);
    tabFipsCounty.addQuery('u_county_name', sourCountyName);
    tabFipsCounty.query();

    if (tabFipsCounty.next()) {
        return tabFipsCounty.u_county_name;
    } else {
        ignore = true;

        var countyExists = false;
        var stateExists = false;

        var gr = new GlideRecord('u_fips_county');
        gr.addQuery('u_county_name', sourCountyName);
        gr.setLimit(1);
        gr.query();
        if (gr.hasNext()) {
            countyExists = true;
        }

        var grState = new GlideRecord('u_fips_county');
        grState.addQuery('u_county_full_state_name', sourStateCode);
        grState.setLimit(1);
        grState.query();
        if (grState.hasNext()) {
            stateExists = true;
        }

        if (stateExists && !countyExists) {
            log.error('There is no county named ' + sourCountyName + ' in the state of ' + sourStateCode + '.');
        } else if (!stateExists && countyExists) {
            log.error('The state two letter code, ' + sourStateCode + ', is misspelled or not a valid state.');
        } else {
            log.error('There is no county, ' + sourCountyName + ', and/or state, ' + sourStateCode + ', in the FIPS County table.');
        }
    }

    //Below footer line used by ServiceNow for Transform Script
})(source, map, log, target);
```

for error scenario, ideally you could collect all the errors and then process them in some schedule job so that your tranformScript is faster.